# Injecting a simple class in controller nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, nestjs, interceptor

So basically I have a controller which is using a decorator 'UseInterceptor' in that I am passing a class which is calling a method but I feel I am not doing the right way it should be. I need someone who could help me in defining a better way to maintain the singularity of the controller class.Here is the code

**icons.controller.ts**

```
var uploadOptions = new InterceptorClass(); ----> This bugs me and ---doesn't feel right way of doing.
const filesize = 512 * 512;
const driverFilesize = 512 * 512;

@Controller('icons')

export class IconsController {
    constructor(
        
        private iconsService: IconsService) { }
  @Post('/marker/')
    @UseGuards(CustomAccessGuard)
    @UseRoles({
        resource: ModuleNames.ICONS,
        action: "create",
        possession: "own"
    })
    @UseInterceptors(uploadOptions.uploadInterceptor(filesize)) ----> This is where I am using it.
    async uploadMarkerFile(
        @UploadedFile() file,
        @GetUser() user,
        @FileValidator() validator
    ) {

        let result = await this.iconsService.uploadFile(file, IconEntityType.MARKER, user);
        return new SuccessResponse(true, "Successfully Uploaded", result);
    }
}
```

**file.service.ts**
For Reference..

```
import { FileInterceptor } from "@nestjs/platform-express"
import { memoryStorage } from 'multer';
import { editFileName, imageFileFilter } from "../icons/utils/file-upload.utils";

export class InterceptorClass {

    constructor() { }

    uploadInterceptor(fileSize: number) {
        const UploadInterceptor = FileInterceptor('file', {
            storage: memoryStorage({
                // destination: './src/assets/marker/icons',
                filename: editFileName
            }),
            fileFilter: imageFileFilter,
            limits: {
                files: 1,
                fileSize: fileSize
            }
        });
        return UploadInterceptor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply wrap the `FileInterceptor` decorator in your own decorator where you initialize it with the given config:

```
// in file custom-file.interceptor.ts

import { editFileName, imageFileFilter } from "../icons/utils/file-upload.utils";

export function CustomFileInterceptor(fileSize) {
    const UploadInterceptor = FileInterceptor('file', {
        storage: memoryStorage({
            // destination: './src/assets/marker/icons',
            filename: editFileName
        }),
        fileFilter: imageFileFilter,
        limits: {
            files: 1,
            fileSize
        }
    });
    return UploadInterceptor;
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
import {CustomFileInterceptor} from "./custom-file.interceptor";
...

@UseInterceptors(CustomFileInterceptor(512))
async uploadMarkerFile(...)
```

Comment: @Hareem rehan: any feedback?